# Create Input::get reusable array (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a controller that receives input from a from. My controller handles both the **create** and the **update** in different functions.

Is there a way that I can create an **array / function** of sorts that I can then call in both locations so that I don't have to repeat the same code bellow in the **create** and **update** functions?

```
$client->company_name           = Input::get('company_name');
$client->telephone              = Input::get('telephone');
$client->website                = Input::get('website');
$client->building_name          = Input::get('building_name');
$client->street_address         = Input::get('street_address');
$client->town                   = Input::get('town');
```

I've created the rules array (below), I just need to try to do the same for the input values.

```
/**
 * create the validation rules for database input
 *
 * @return array
 */
private function rules()
{

    $rules = array(
        'company_name'      => 'required',
        'telephone'         => 'required',
        'website'           => 'url',
        'building_name'     => '',
        'street_address'    => '',
        'town'              => '',
    );

    return $rules;

}
```

Thanks all, I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Yes, you can. But was in exactly your problem? What's your question? With what you have a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Marcin. I'm trying to prevent having to repeat the same code twice in 2 different functions so I need a method that will allow me to create it once (the first code block above) and then call it in 2 seperate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, you need to use this function

```
function modifyClient($client) {

    $client->company_name           = Input::get('company_name');
    $client->telephone              = Input::get('telephone');
    $client->website                = Input::get('website');
    $client->building_name          = Input::get('building_name');
    $client->street_address         = Input::get('street_address');
    $client->town                   = Input::get('town');

}
```

and if you create new client you can use:

```
$client = new Client;
modifyClient($client);
```

and if you modify you can do:

```
$client = Client::find($id);
modifyClient($client);
```

And after both of them you can save it into DB using

```
$client->save();
```